# INSERT in MySQL doesn't work for second time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with a MySQL request. Insertion doesn't work overnight. I don't know why. it is second time he doing this.

I am getting the following mysqli_error:

> Erreur :You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 ,'ljhb', '5456', '0-aVeeRYLr-fruits-et-legumes-bio-' at line 1

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
 $name = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT name FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE name='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,stripcslashes($_POST['name']))."'")
                or die('Erreur :'.mysqli_error());
 $nombre = mysqli_query($connect,"SELECT nombre FROM fruitandvegetable WHERE nombre='".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,stripcslashes($_POST['nombre']))."'")
                or die('Erreur :'.mysqli_error());

if(mysqli_num_rows($name) != 0) {
      $doublonName = "The name already exists";
}                    

if(mysqli_num_rows($nombre) != 0) {
      $doublonNombre = "The number already exists";
}         

elseif(mysqli_num_rows($name) == 0 && mysqli_num_rows($nombre) == 0) { 
    $query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO fruitandvegetable(id, name, color,description, nombre, type, image_name) VALUES('', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['name'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$color)." ,
                     '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$type)." ,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$description)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['nombre'])."',
                      '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$image_name)."')")

              or die('Erreur :'.mysqli_error($connect)); 

    $erreur = "Votre Fruit Et Legume a bien été pris en compte";  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `'`s.

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$color)." ,

'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$type)." ,
```

Try this -

```
$query = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO fruitandvegetable(id, name, color,description, nombre, type, image_name) VALUES('', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['name'])."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$color)."' ,
                 '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$type)."' ,'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$description)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$_POST['nombre'])."',
                  '".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$image_name)."')");
```

Comment: i can't, i don't know why

Comment: you dont have enough reps.. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$color)." ,
```

replace above with below

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$color)."' ,
```

and this

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$type)."
```

with

```
'".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$type)."'
```